# Sort and describe itinerary segments

Tags: javascript, beginner, sorting, json, graph

Given some incoming some data in JSON format, representing unsorted train, bus, and flight tickets:

```
[{'from':'A', to:'B',...}, {'from':'C', to:'D',...}, {'from':'B', to:'C',...}];
```

… I must sort tickets (A-B-B-C-C-D) and generate text (description) with all information about each trip (number of flight, gate, seat - it comes with JSON objects). But with some requirements:

- it must be "API format".
  extensible code (should provide way to add information about different type of transport).
- clean and easy code.

I want to be honest with you, imagine that I'm junior in your team, and that I write for real project.

Here is my solution.

```js
var tickets = [
    {
        from: "London",
        to: "Paris",
        transportType: "train",
        transport: {
            "number": "54S",
            "seat": "23"
        }
    },
    {
        from: "Berlin",
        to: "Akrich",
        transportType: "bus",
        transport: {
            "number": "SR465",
            "seat": "56",
            "gate": "2A",
        }
    },
    {
        from: "Paris",
        to: "Berlin",
        transportType: "flight",
        transport: {
            "number": "SR465",
            "seat": "56",
            "gate": "2A",
            "baggage": "will be automatically transferred from your last leg"
        }
    },
    {
        from: "Moscow",
        to: "London",
        transportType: "flight",
        transport: {
            "number": "N554",
            "seat": "4A",
            "gate": "22",
            "baggage": "drop at ticket counter 344"
        }
    }
];


function TripSorter ( tickets ) {
    this.from = {};
    this.to = {};

    this.path = [];
    this.tickets = [];

    if ( tickets ) {
        this.importTickets( tickets );
    }
}

// copy data in this.tickets. 
// create "from" ( contains only "from" points of route ) and "to" objects (hashMap);
TripSorter.prototype.importTickets = function ( tickets ) {
    var self = this;
    self.tickets = [];

    if ( tickets instanceof Array ) {
        self.tickets = tickets;

        tickets.forEach( function( e, i ) {

           if ( !e.from || e.from === ' ' ) {
               console.error('card.from - is missing on ' + JSON.stringify(e, undefined, 2));
           } else if ( !e.to || e.to === ' ' ) {
               console.error('card.to - is missing on ' + JSON.stringify(e, undefined, 2));
           } else {
               self.from[e.from] = i;
               self.to[e.to] = i;
           }
            
        });       

    }
};

// start of trip - unique key in obj from compared to obj to.
TripSorter.prototype.getStartTrip = function () {
    var i = 0,
        start;

    for (  ; i < this.tickets.length; i++ ) {
        if( this.to[this.tickets[i].from] == null ) {
            start = this.tickets[i].from;
            break;
        }
    }

    return start;
};

// obj "from" and "to" contains equal value for different keys
// ticket {from: A, to: B} => var from = { A : 0 }, to = { B : 0};
TripSorter.prototype.buildTrip = function () {
    var start = this.getStartTrip(),
        point = this.from[start],
        next,
        i = 0;

    for (  ; i < this.tickets.length; i++ ) {
        if ( !this.tickets[point] ) continue;
        next = this.tickets[point].to;
        this.path.push(this.tickets[this.to[next]]);
        point = this.from[next];
    }
};

TripSorter.prototype.getTrip = function () {
    var text = [];
    this.path.forEach( function( card ) {
        switch (card.transportType) {
            case 'flight':
                text.push( new Flight(card).message );
            break;
            case 'train':
                text.push( new Train(card).message );
            break;
            case 'bus':
                text.push( new Bus(card).message);
            break;
            default: break;
        };
    });
    return text;
};

var trip = new TripSorter(tickets);
trip.buildTrip();
var route = trip.getTrip();

console.log(route);

//Generate trip description. 
function Transport (data) {
    this.from = data.from;
    this.to = data.to;
    this.type = data.transportType;

    this.place = 'from ' + this.from + ' to ' + this.to; // ?

    this.seat = (data.transport.seat) ? ' Seat ' + data.transport.seat + '.' : ' No seat assignment.';
    this.gate = (data.transport.gate) ? ' Geat ' + data.transport.gate + '.' : '';

    this.number = (data.transport.number) ? ' ' + data.transport.number + ' ' : ' ';
    this.baggage = ' Baggage' + data.transport.baggage || '';
}    

function Train(data) {
    Transport.call(this, data);
    this.message = 'Take train' + this.number + this.place + '.' + this.seat;
    return this.m;
}
Train.prototype = Object.create(Transport.prototype);
Train.prototype.constructor = Train;

function Flight(data) {
    Transport.call(this, data);

    this.number = 'take flight' + this.number; // ?
    this.place = 'From ' + this.from + ',' + this.number + 'to ' + this.to + '.'; // ?

    this.message = this.place + this.gate + this.seat + this.baggage;
    return this.m;
}
Flight.prototype = Object.create(Transport.prototype);
Flight.prototype.constructor = Flight;

function Bus(data) {
    Transport.call(this, data);
    this.message = 'Take the bus' + this.number  + this.place + '.' + this.seat;
    return this.m;
}
Bus.prototype = Object.create(Transport.prototype);
Bus.prototype.constructor = Bus;
```

Is it ok that I used:

- function constructor and Prototype instead of usual function ?
- different types of array loop — `for` and `forEach` in one constructor?

How I should organize code inside of this file (where to place "transport constructor" and where "TripSorter")?

Is it correct to use `Transport` constructor and inherit from it or I must used switch(type of transport) - case (message + )? What way is easy to extend?

I must add some functionality to print generated text to html - is it ok that I put it inside of `TripSorter` prototype or its better to use different function?

I used `console.error` to handle error of ticket format — is it correct way?

Are the comments normal?

Comment: TripSorter... do you have [a background in Java](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.de/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)?

Comment: Hi there: what do you mean by "API format"?

Comment: Thank for article (Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns), now I realized some of naming problems.

"API format" maybe I have wrong representation about what API is. But I must solve this task in format of module (or like library) - it accept some data, give some methods to work with this data and return correct description.

Answer (score 2):

**Organization**

> How I should organize code inside of this file (where to place
>   "transport constructor" and where "TripSorter")?

Declare things before using them. Declare dependencies first.

- Function declarations and class definitions (constructor functions) go to the top, example data and code to the bottom.
- `TripSorter` instantiates and holds `Transport` instances, so declare `Transport` first.

**Inheritance**

> Is it correct to use Transport constructor and inherit from it or I
>   must used switch(type of transport) - case (message + )? What way is
>   easy to extend?

Inheritance is an extensible approach. However, it requires some overhead and you need to declare some kind of factory function - here: `getTrip`. This function features a switch statement. In JavaScript, it is often advised to replace switch statements with maps, usually object literals.

Also, your `Transport` objects currently don't have any methods. They even don't hold any meaningful data apart from one `message` attribute. Once the constructor function returns an instance, you just use it to retrieve the `message`.

Additionally, by pushing subclass functionality which is shared by some but not all subclasses - e.g. initialization of `gate` and `baggage` - upwards to the parent `Transport` constructor, you attempt to reduce code repetition at the cost of clear semantics and maintainable code:

```
let train = new Train({
  from: "Beijing",
  to: "Tianjin",
  transport: {number: "CR120"}
});
// Why do trains have a gate and baggage attribute?
console.log(train); // Object { type: undefined, gate: "", baggage: "...", ... }
```

You redundantly store type information in the `type` attribute. However, your `Transport` instances already have type information attached to them:

```
train instanceof Train // true
```

I suggest you ditch inheritance and the additional overhead by directly mapping transport types to functions (which are objects, too) which return descriptions:

```
const descriptors = {
  "walk": (from, to) => `Walk from ${from} to ${to}.`,
  ...
}
descriptors["walk"]("Berlin", "Hamburg"); // Walk from Berlin to Hamburg.
```

**Constructor functions**

Don't return anything from a constructor function. You currently return `this.m` in `Train`, `Flight` and so on. Luckily, `this.m` is `undefined` - and when returning `undefined` from a constructor function, [the new operator returns the newly created object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**API design**

Your `TripSorter` is stateful and its methods must be called in a correct order. Calling `importTickets(tickets)` after already having supplied tickets to the constructor results in unexpected behavior. Calling `getTrip` before `buildTrip` is meaningless. Et cetera. I don't see any good reason to split one indivisible 'sort tickets' functionality into several public methods.

**Print results**

> I must add some functionality to print generated text to html - is it
>   ok that I put it inside of TripSorter prototype or its better to use
>   different function?

So far, you defined some models and business logic. You should not mix those with presentation logic - this should be part of your 'view' layer. By keeping those parts of your application separate, you can test and reuse them much easier.

**Error handling**

> I used console.error to handle error of ticket format — is it correct
>   way?

Your `TripSorter.prototype.importTicket` methods logs errors to the console when the `from` or `to` attribute of a ticket is missing. However, it still resumes operations and returns the first connected sub-trip, ignoring other connected segments.

Also, you do explicitly check for single-space strings but still accept multi-space strings:

```
if ( !e.from || e.from === ' ' ) { ... }
```

You also don't check for cycles and you don't validate the `transportType` and `transport` attribute. In some cases, you simply ignore the incorrect ticket and continue silently, sometimes you throw a `TypeError` and sometimes, you log an error to the console. All in all, your input validation and error handling feels incomplete and random.

I suggest you write robust code that expects valid tickets but still returns consistent results for 'invalid' attributes. Your `TripSorter` cannot possibly validate from and to attributes, as the knowledge about valid city names is part of another business unit in your code. You could / should therefore validate tickets beforehand and e.g. encapsulate them in a class that doesn't allow construction of invalid tickets. Fail early and document clearly how and when you fail:

```
// @throws {Error} when itinerary is ambiguous or circular.
```

**Comments**

> Are the comments normal?

Your comments mainly focus on implementation details:

```
// start of trip - unique key in obj from compared to obj to.
TripSorter.prototype.getStartTrip = function () { ... }
```

However, I recommend more 'documentation style' comments that tell the users of your functions, classes and modules about their purpose, the expected inputs and return values. Following an established format such as [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/manual/usage/tags.html) that is understood by many also allows you to auto-generate your documentation:

```
/**
 * Get the city where the trip starts.
 *
 * @return {String} city.
 */
TripSorter.prototype.getStartTrip = function () { ... }
```

**Local variables**

Declare and initialize loop iterators within the loop initializer. Keep variables as local as possible. `let` is more local than `var`. Instead of

```
var foo,
    i = 0;

for (  ; i < length; i++ ) {
  foo = ...
}
```

I suggest you write

```
for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
  let foo = ...
}
```

**Functional vs. declarative**

Better don't mix functional style iterations

```
 this.path.forEach( function( card ) { ... }
```

and for-loops

```
 for (  ; i < this.tickets.length; i++ ) { ... }
```

needlessly, unless it improves readability.

**Naming**

Name your generic function arguments:

```
 tickets.forEach( function( e, i ) { ... } );       // what is e?
 tickets.forEach( function( element, i ) { ... } ); // it is an element...
 tickets.forEach( function( ticket, i ) { ... } );  // it is a ticket!
```

Avoid misleading names - is this really a 'place'?

```
this.place = 'From ' + this.from + ',' + this.number + 'to ' + this.to + '.';
```

Most of your constructors feature a single generic, nondescript `data` argument. Instead of

```
function Transport (data) {
   this.from = data.from;
   this.to = data.to;
   ...
}
```

I suggest the self-documenting

```
function Transport ({from, to} = data) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    ...
}
```

or simply

```
function Transport (from, to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    ...
}
```

**Strict type checking**

Don't check argument types:

```
if ( tickets instanceof Array ) { ... }
```

Use comments to state the expected type or interface. By removing above type check and writing

```
for (let ticket of tickets) { ... }
```

you can handle any iterable `tickets` argument. It also doesn't fail silently but throws a `TypeError: ... is not iterable` if needed.

**Weak comparison**

Be cautious of weak comparisons:

```
if( this.to[this.tickets[i].from] == null )
```

Accessing an inexistent key from `this.to` actually returns `undefined`. And luckily for you, `undefined == null` evaluates to `true`.

**Other issues**

I don't think this is correct as the `+` operator has higher precedence than `||`:

```
this.baggage = ' Baggage' + data.transport.baggage || '';
```

**Suggested alternative implementation**

Applying above suggestions to your code:

```js
/**
 * Return tickets in connecting order with successively matching
 * to - from attributes.
 *
 * @param {Object[]} tickets - unordered tickets.
 * @return {Object[]} connecting tickets.
 * @throws {Error} when itinerary is ambiguous or circular.
 */
function findItinerary(tickets) {
  let from = new Map(tickets.map(ticket => [ticket.from, ticket]));
  let to = new Map(tickets.map(ticket => [ticket.to, ticket]));
  let start = tickets.find(ticket => !to.has(ticket.from));
  
  if (!start) {
    throw Error(`Circular itinerary`);
  }
  
  let itinerary = [];
  for (let ticket = start; ticket; ticket = from.get(ticket.to)) {
    itinerary.push(ticket);
  }
  
  if (itinerary.length < tickets.length) {
    throw Error(`Ambiguous itinerary`);
  }
  
  return itinerary;
}

/**
 * Map tickets to descriptions returned by matching descriptor functions
 * based on the ticket transport type.
 *
 * @param {Object[]} tickets - connecting tickets.
 * @param {Object} descriptors - mapping transport types to descriptor functions.
 * @return {String[]} descriptions.
 * @throws {Error} when a transport type has no matching descriptor.
 */
function describeItinerary(tickets, descriptors) {
  return tickets.map(ticket => {
    let descriptor = descriptors[ticket.transportType];
    if (descriptor) {
      return descriptor(ticket.from, ticket.to, ticket.transport);
    } else {
      throw Error(`Missing descriptor for transport type ${ticket.transportType}`);
    }
  });
}

// Extensible ticket descriptors:
const descriptors = {
  "flight": function(from, to, {number, gate, seat, baggage} = transport) {
    return `From ${from}, take flight ${number} to ${to}.`
      + `${gate ? ` Gate ${gate}.` : ``}`
      + `${seat ? ` Seat ${seat}`  : ` No seat assignment`}.`   
      + ` Baggage ${baggage}`;
  },
  "bus": function(from, to, {number, seat, gate} = transport) {
    return `Take the bus ${number} from ${from} to ${to}.`
      + `${gate ? ` Gate ${gate}.` : ``}`
      + `${seat ? ` Seat ${seat}`  : ` No seat assignment`}.`;
  },
  "train": function(from, to, {number, seat} = transport) {
    return `Take train ${number} from ${from} to ${to}.`
      + `${seat ? ` Seat ${seat}`  : ` No seat assignment`}.`;
  }
};

// Example tickets:
let tickets = [
  {
    from: "London",
    to: "Paris",
    transportType: "train",
    transport: {
      "number": "54S",
      "seat": "23"
    }
  },
  {
    from: "Berlin",
    to: "Akrich",
    transportType: "bus",
    transport: {
      "number": "SR465",
      "seat": "56",
      "gate": "2A"
    }
  },
  {
    from: "Paris",
    to: "Berlin",
    transportType: "flight",
    transport: {
      "number": "SR465",
      "seat": "56",
      "gate": "2A",
      "baggage": "will be automatically transferred from your last leg"
    }
  },
  {
    from: "Moscow",
    to: "London",
    transportType: "flight",
    transport: {
      "number": "N554",
      "seat": "4A",
      "gate": "22",
      "baggage": "drop at ticket counter 344"
    }
  }
];

// Find itinerary and describe it:
let itinerary = findItinerary(tickets);
let description = describeItinerary(itinerary, descriptors);

console.log(description);
```

Comment: Wow, how much wrong things now I realize. Thank you very much.